# ImageMagick trouble

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

Every time I try to download a pdf file, ImageMagick is launched and fails to render the file. How do I get rid of or disable ImageMagick?

Comment: Right-click any saved PDF > Properties > Open with...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ChanganAuto for providing the hint.

Right-click any saved PDF file to select the 'Properties' from the dropdown. Select 'open with' in the 'Properties' window to deselect the 'ImageMagick' and select the appropriate software (Document Viewer)to open the pdf files.